# Problem with drush and site alias (Drupal 8.8.6 / Drush 10.3.1)

Tags: 8, drush

I've installed two drupal sites on a share hosting (OVH), in two folders :

- dev.www
- www

I've installed drush 10.3.1 and create two alias, but when I try use alias (drush @dev status), I have the follow error :

```
[warning] Drush command terminated abnormally.
```

I don't know if my drush configuration or aliases are good or bad. Here is my configuration in .drush/sites/the-choices.site.yml:

```
'@the-choice.dev':
  remote-host: ...
  user: ...
  root: /home/thechoc/dev.www
  uri: 'http://dev.the-choice.org'
  ssh:
    options: '-o PasswordAuthentication=no -i /home/thechoc/dev.www/insecure_private_key'
'@the-choice.prod':
  host: ...
  user: ...
  root: /home/thechoc/www
  uri: 'https://the-choice.org'
  ssh:
    options: '-o PasswordAuthentication=no -i /home/thechoc/www/insecure_private_key'
```

If someone can help me. Thank in advance.

Comment: You can run drush with the ```--debug``` flag to have more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the leading `@name` and try adding the full path to drush for all remote environments:

```
dev:
  ...
  paths:
    drush-script: /example/path/www/vendor/drush/drush/drush
prod:
  ...
  paths:
    drush-script: /foo/bar/www/vendor/drush/drush/drush
```

Comment: Hi @Hudri and @sonfd, tahnk you for your answers.
I made a new file with only these lines: 
dev:
  remote-host: ...
  user: ...
  root: /home/thechoc/dev.www
  uri: http://dev.the-choice.org
  
prod:
  host: ...
  user: ...
  root: /home/thechoc/www
  uri: https://the-choice.org

 but when I try to run drush @the-choice.prod status, I have tthe follow error :       
 `The command "ssh -t -o PasswordAuthentication=no thechoc@... 'drush status --uri=https://the-choice.org --root=/home/thechoc/www'" failed.`

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues with what you're doing here.

1. As Hudri mentioned, you don't want the site name piece of the alias inside your aliases file. That part of the drush alias is determined by the alias file name.
2. When you use your alias, you should use use it like `drush @sitename.env status`, using the full alias name.

In your case, remove the `@the-choice` piece from your environment keys in your *.drush/sites/the-choices.site.yml* alias file, e.g.

```
'dev':
  remote-host: ...
  user: ...
  root: /home/thechoc/dev.www
  uri: 'http://dev.the-choice.org'
  ssh:
    options: '-o PasswordAuthentication=no -i /home/thechoc/dev.www/insecure_private_key'
'prod':
  host: ...
  user: ...
  root: /home/thechoc/www
  uri: 'https://the-choice.org'
  ssh:
    options: '-o PasswordAuthentication=no -i /home/thechoc/www/insecure_private_key'
```

With the above configuration and your alias file named *the-choices.site.yml*, you'll interact with the two sites like: `drush @the-choices.dev status` or `drush @the-choices.prod status`.